# Ubuntu 16.04 x6 Monitor setup with MST Hub and AMD RX 580 8GB

Tags: multiple-monitors, xorg.conf

I recently bought x6 ASUS 24inch monitors for my battle station and I’m having a tad bit of an issue setting up the MST Hub to get the extra 3 working.

I’m entirely new to xorg configurations, and i have a unique case here, any help would be much appreciated. In ubuntu 16.04 with AMD GPU Pro drivers running on a RX 580 8GB. 1 HDMI + 2 DP (3 monitors without hub) works fine. Plug in the Hub into the 3rd DP nothing in the MST Hub. it still runs fine.

Plug a HDMI to DP cable from the monitor to the hub for the remaining 3 monitors. As soon as i plug the first monitor in it detects it, but only allows 1024×768, also unknown is named on it and does not display anyout put on the monitor. Also it lags / locks up for a good minute.Plug in another monitor and it just craps out to black screen. Did a variation of boots with all of them plugged into the MST HUB, and so on. No joy.

Any ideas? Also thank you for your time.

MST HUB: http://club-3d.com/en/detail/2434/

https://pastebin.com/khq9c0qG - xrandr - WITH HUB NO MONITORS PLUGGED IN
https://pastebin.com/ECPexCcM - xrandr - WITH HUB PLUGGED IN and another Monitor on it.

Here's what it looks like with one monitor plugged into the Hub. After it gets done locking up for a few minutes it displays the following from a screenshot. (Does not actually display the 1024x768 on any monitors, does show the x3 monitors connected to the GPU tho..)